# Why don't the bounds in this definite integral change?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bounds-of-integration

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i589D.png)

This is probably a very basic question but I'm having a brain lapse and don't know why they didn't change the definite integral bounds from ($0 \rightarrow4$) to ($4 \rightarrow20$). I know that using $u$-sub, you would have $u = x^2 + 4$. So why are the bounds seemingly not affected?

Comment: There's no u sub being done.

Comment: Substitution is a tool to help find antiderivatives. In the end you don't need to always do it and the number that pops out is the same. (Nice use of the MATH 152 common exam.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that a $u$-substitution was not (explicitly) used, though it was implicitly used and the details somewhat skipped over. However, they converted back into terms of $x$, instead of staying in terms of $u$.

In the first integral, you have that $u=x^2+4$ gives $\mathrm{d} u = 2x \, \mathrm{d} x$, so

$$\int_0^4 \frac{x}{x^2 + 4} \, \mathrm{d} x
= \int_4^{20} \frac{1/2}{u} \, \mathrm{d} u$$

You can finish this in, evidently, your preferred method:

$$\int_4^{20} \frac{1/2}{u} \, \mathrm{d} u = \frac 1 2 \ln|u| \bigg|_{u=4}^{u=20} = \frac 12 \ln(20) - \frac 1 2 \ln(4)$$

You can also use the shown method of converting back to $x$, but you will get the same answer.

$$\int_4^{20} \frac{1/2}{u} \, \mathrm{d} u
= \frac 12 \ln|u| \bigg|_{u=4}^{u=20}
= \frac 1 2 \ln(x^2+1) \bigg|_{x=0}^{x=4}$$

This idea holds in general: if you do a $u$-substitution, you don't *have* to change the bounds, so long as you convert back into terms of $x$ the moment you've found an antiderivative, before you plug in the bounds of the integral.

In my opinion this is undesirable since $u$-substitutions are meant to simplify the form of the antiderivative, which means converting back to $x$ can result in something unpleasant to plug numbers into, while the expression in terms of $u$ may be more pleasant. (Of course there can be a slight trade-off of the bounds often being more unpleasant in the $u$ case, but I think the elegance of the antiderivative outweighs that.)

---

*Addendum 1:* A third means to handle the integral is that

$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \, \mathrm{d} x = \ln |f(x)| + C$$

for suitable $f$, so one can circumvent implied or explicit $u$-substitution altogether by the identity above and realizing

$$\int_0^4 \frac{x}{x^2 + 4} \, \mathrm{d} x
= \frac 1 2 \int_0^4 \frac{2x}{x^2 + 4} \, \mathrm{d} x$$

Granted, the stated identity is also just an implication of $u$-sub, so I'd hesitate to say this method *truly* avoids $u$-substitution.

---

*Addendum 2:* Be mindful of which integral you're using the $u$-substitution on; I see this often with my Calculus I/II students where they identify the $u$-substitution but don't realize its resulting differential just does not mesh well with the integral unless further work is done. In the original integral of

$$\int_0^4 \frac{x+2}{x^2 + 4} \, \mathrm{d} x$$

$u=x^2+4$ does not work, since there is no pleasant way to handle the $+2$ in this scenario beyond noting that $x = \pm \sqrt{u-4}$, but this only makes things messier.

I felt like bringing this up since technically, one can argue the second integral (that becomes $\arctan(\cdots)$) also implicitly uses $u$-substitution in an analogous way, but the substitution would be very differently.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no $u$ substitution written down.

*If* substitution is used, *then* it was done in the head and reversed for the text.

$$\begin{align}\int_0^4 \dfrac{x~\mathrm d x}{x^2+4} &=\dfrac 12\int_4^{20}\dfrac{\mathrm d u}{u}\\&=\left.\dfrac 12\ln(u)\right\rvert_4^{20}\\&=\left.\dfrac 12\ln(x^2+4)\right\rvert_0^{4}
\end{align}$$